# How to create a custom OAuth 2.0 redirect_uri for Google provider, for UWP app?

Tags: uwp, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I want to register a custom redirect_uri (like pw.oauth2:/oauth2redirect) in Google Developer console for a native application (this is the recommended approach for UWP apps). According to https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#request-parameter-redirect_uri, there must be an option to select "Custom URI scheme (Android, iOS, UWP)" but I only see these options:

- Web application
- Android
- Chrome
- iOS
- Other

Selecting Other does not let me specify redirect_uri.

How am I supposed to register a custom redirect_uri for a UWP app?

If I don't register a redirect_uri, I'm getting redirect_uri_mismatch error during OAuth authorization process.

The ClientID in this github sample https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/tree/master/OAuthUniversalApp works. Looks like for this ClientID the required_uri registered. But how to achieve the same for my own ClientIDs?

This old question discusses something similar but it has never been replied either:
[Google APIs for UWP not playing nice with custom redirect scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462403/google-apis-for-uwp-not-playing-nice-with-custom-redirect-scheme)

EDIT:
To clarify. I'm using the Google sample mentioned above (https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/tree/master/OAuthUniversalApp). It works with hardcoded ClientID provided by Google. I just can't get it working with my own ClientID as I see no way to register my own redirect_uri in their Developer Console.

Answer (score 5):

Got it (after some trial and error). In Google Developer Console, you need to create iOS app. In app properties, you need to specify the URL scheme (taken from **Package Manifest / Declarations / Protocol / Name** of UWP app project in Visual Studio) in Bundle ID parameter.

AppStore ID and Team ID can remain empty.

The Bundle ID acts as a URL scheme. In my case, I specified *pw.oauth2* value (it's the value in Google sample). Then I saved changes, set ClientID of iOS app in the Google UWP sample and found that everything is working properly now.

Google Console provides **iOS URL scheme** parameter in iOS app properties (something like *com.googleusercontent.apps.6284700xxxxx-6tp4d3xxxxx*). Ignore this value for a UWP app. Only Bundle ID matters.

Comment: after your following steps it works but how to upload image or document on google drive ? do you have any code sample ? in uwp. in my sample code i am trying to open the `authorizationRequest` in WebView control. so how to catch the response ?

Comment: Once you got the access_token, it should be very easy to use it for working with files or whatever and should be a lot of samples on Google (they don't need to be UWP specific). I didn't do file upload (I retrieved the user profile) but it shouldn't be much different. Getting access_token was the most tricky part (and UWP-specific).

Comment: have you tried to open in WebView  control ? because i am not getting response after login to google drive and allow application(follow the necessary steps) but i am not getting response :(

Comment: every time in `OnNavigatedTo` function i got the `e.Parameter` with empty string

Comment: You should open a browser, not WebView. `var success = Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(authorizationRequest));`

Comment: ok even if i am opening in browser. after allowing application nothing is happening

Comment: Did you register the uri scheme which makes your UWP app open when the protocol opened in the browser starts with that scheme?

Comment: yes it redirects to my uwp application after  set yes  to the google drive popup. but my question is where is the response and token ?

Comment: it works its my fault after entering the another account credentials it works thank you for your valuable reply. :)

Comment: Works great with UWP and I get the response.. with an access and refresh token. now i can move onto the Calendar API

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

Are you trying to use `WebAuthenticationBroker` in UWP to prompt a user to sign in? In which case you can't customize your `redirect_uri` in UWP... it must be gotten from `WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri()` which represents your 
`Package SID`... Looks something like this: `ms-app://s-1-15-2-1374842229...`

and

Make sure you're properly encoding and decoding your redirect_uri- it will mismatch if you do this wrong. Without your code it's hard to tell how you're doing this.

`WebUtility.UrlEncode(redirectURI);`

Comment: The code was mentioned in my question - https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/tree/master/OAuthUniversalApp (it's even not my code, it's Google's).  As I said, it works with the original ClientID hardcoded there but not with my own ClientID. And for my own ClientID I can't change redirect_uri in Google Developer Console.

Comment: And no, their code does not use WebAuthenticationBroker, neither does it use Google API libraries.

Comment: @visc -  in my sample code i am trying to open the `authorizationRequest` in WebView control. so how to catch the response ? do you have any code sample ?

Comment: this will not you get error as "The content in this section has been provided by the app developer. This content has not been reviewed or verified by Google."