# UWP OnNavigatedTo is not firing when returned to from an Oauth redirect Uri

Tags: c#, uwp, oauth, google-authentication

To start - I have taken the sample UWP app provided by Google here (https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/tree/master/OAuthUniversalApp).

I have this successfully working with my own clientID (which the setup was documented in the answer here: [How to create a custom OAuth 2.0 redirect_uri for Google provider, for UWP app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705031/how-to-create-a-custom-oauth-2-0-redirect-uri-for-google-provider-for-uwp-app)). The redirect back into the app works fine - and is fired from the OnNavigatedTo() method in the sample.

I then have an UWP that logs temperature from a sensor (which will eventually run on a Raspberry Pi) - but for now I'm running this on normal Windows 10. I have copied the Oauth bits from the sample into my project - and also declared the protocol in the Package.appxmanifest using the name "pw.oauth2" (the same as the sample and also matches what I have in the Google Developer Console).

When I launch the app and click the "Sign in with Google" it successfully launches the browser, requests authorizations/sign-in, and redirects back to the app. I know this part is working because it brings the app back to the foreground. However the OnNavigatedTo() method is not firing when returning to my app.

I've search and read the documentation for this - but am unable to get that method to fire in my app. I feel like I missing something else that was setup in the sample app that I have not configured in my app. Any help or suggestions is appreciated!

Here is my XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="CamIOT.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CamIOT"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <RelativePanel>
            <Button x:Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="206" Height="46" Click="oauth_Click"
                BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" Background="Transparent">
                <Image Source="Assets/btn_google_sign-in.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="206"/>
            </Button>

            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxOutput" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=""
                IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="300,40,0,0" Height="731" Width="1000"/>
            <ScrollViewer Margin="12,100,12,12">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                 I2C Device Data
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                    Temperature and Humidity Data
                    </TextBlock>
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <Image Source="Assets/i2c_sample_bb.jpg" Stretch="None" Margin="2,10,2,0" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                    <Button x:Name="StartStopButton" Content="Start" Margin="0,10,0,0" Click="{x:Bind StartStopScenario}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ScenarioControls" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    Current Temperature: <Run x:Name="CurrentTemp"/>
                    <LineBreak/>
                    Current Humidity: <Run x:Name="CurrentHumidity"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </RelativePanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here is my OnNavigatedTo() Method:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnNavigatedTo Fired!");

            if (e.Parameter is Uri)
            {
                // Gets URI from navigation parameters.
                Uri authorizationResponse = (Uri)e.Parameter;
                string queryString = authorizationResponse.Query;
                output("MainPage received authorizationResponse: " + authorizationResponse);

                // Parses URI params into a dictionary
                // ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11957114/72176
                Dictionary<string, string> queryStringParams =
                        queryString.Substring(1).Split('&')
                             .ToDictionary(c => c.Split('=')[0],
                                           c => Uri.UnescapeDataString(c.Split('=')[1]));

                if (queryStringParams.ContainsKey("error"))
                {
                    output(String.Format("OAuth authorization error: {0}.", queryStringParams["error"]));
                    return;
                }

                if (!queryStringParams.ContainsKey("code")
                    || !queryStringParams.ContainsKey("state"))
                {
                    output("Malformed authorization response. " + queryString);
                    return;
                }

                // Gets the Authorization code & state
                string code = queryStringParams["code"];
                string incoming_state = queryStringParams["state"];

                // Retrieves the expected 'state' value from local settings (saved when the request was made).
                ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
                string expected_state = (String)localSettings.Values["state"];

                // Compares the receieved state to the expected value, to ensure that
                // this app made the request which resulted in authorization
                if (incoming_state != expected_state)
                {
                    output(String.Format("Received request with invalid state ({0})", incoming_state));
                    return;
                }

                // Resets expected state value to avoid a replay attack.
                localSettings.Values["state"] = null;

                // Authorization Code is now ready to use!
                output(Environment.NewLine + "Authorization code: " + code);

                string code_verifier = (String)localSettings.Values["code_verifier"];
                performCodeExchangeAsync(code, code_verifier);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Parameter);
            }
        }
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing and why  OnNavigatedTo() fires fine in the sample app, but not in my app?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually solved this on my own - If you are following the Google provided Sample Oauth apps for UWP from link the in the question - you will need to add this method below to your App.xaml.cs class - this will get called when the redirect from Google opens your app. It then navigates to your main page which fires the code within the OnNavigatedTo() method.

```
 protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            // When the app was activated by a Protocol (custom URI scheme), forwards
            // the URI to the MainPage through a Navigate event.
            if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
            {
                // Extracts the authorization response URI from the arguments.
                ProtocolActivatedEventArgs protocolArgs = (ProtocolActivatedEventArgs)args;
                Uri uri = protocolArgs.Uri;
                Debug.WriteLine("Authorization Response: " + uri.AbsoluteUri);

                // Gets the current frame, making one if needed.
                var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
                if (frame == null)
                    frame = new Frame();

                // Opens the URI for "navigation" (handling) on the MainPage.
                frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), uri);
                Window.Current.Content = frame;
                Window.Current.Activate();
            }
        }
```